# unable to get article id - createPages

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to create new pages and display related data based on the article ID. But, I am running into issues. Right now I create a slug/id which brings up my article template and creates a link seen in the browser window.

I am not able to display any related data on those article pages. What I want is to find the ID of the page and show the information related to that ID. This is my configuration so far:

gatsby-node.js:

```
const path = require(`path`)

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const articleTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/article.js`)
  return graphql(`
    {
        umdHub {
          articles {
            data {
              id
              title
              subtitle
              body
              summary
              hero_image {
                url_1200_630
              }
              authorship_date {
                formatted_short
                unix
                unix_int
                formatted_long
                formatted_short
                time
              }
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
  `
  ).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
      throw result.errors
    }

    // Create blog post pages.
    result.data.umdHub.articles.data.forEach(data => {
          createPage({
            path: `/articles/${data.slug}-${data.id}`,
            component: articleTemplate,
            id: data.id,
            context: {
              slug: `/articles/${data.slug}-${data.id}`
            },
          })
        })
        return;
  })
}
```

Article template:

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from 'reactstrap';

// eslint-disable-next-line
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Header from "../components/header"
import Footer from "../components/footer"

export default ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data)
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />

      <div className="container spaces article">
        <div className="row">
          <section className="col-md-9">
              <div className="tag-list">
                <ul className="list-inline">
                  <li className="list-inline-item"><a href="/">Highlighted</a></li>
                  <li className="list-inline-item"><a href="/">Innovation</a></li>
                  <li className="list-inline-item"><a href="/">Web Only</a></li>
                  <li className="list-inline-item">February 28, 2019</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <h1>hello</h1>

              {data.umdHub.articles.data.map((article) => (
                <div>
                  <h1>{article.title}</h1>
                </div>
              ))}

              <div className="row article-content">
                <div className="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                  <h2 className="subheader">Subtitle</h2>
                  <div className="author"> 
                    <p>By <a href="/">Jane Doe</a> | Photos by <a href="/">ISTOCK</a></p>
                    <hr />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </section>
          <aside className="col-md-3">
            <div>
              <ListGroup flush>
                <ListGroupItem disabled tag="a" href="#">Recent Posts</ListGroupItem>
                <ListGroupItem tag="a" href="#">Dapibus ac facilisis in</ListGroupItem>
                <span>February 27, 2019</span>
                <ListGroupItem tag="a" href="#">Morbi leo risus</ListGroupItem>
                <span>February 27, 2019</span>
                <ListGroupItem tag="a" href="#">Porta ac consectetur ac</ListGroupItem>
                <span>February 27, 2019</span>
                <ListGroupItem tag="a" href="#">Vestibulum at eros</ListGroupItem>
                <span>February 27, 2019</span>
              </ListGroup>
            </div>
          </aside>
        </div>
      </div>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query($id:String!) {
    umdHub {
      articles(id: $id) {
        data {
          id
          title
          subtitle
          body
          summary
          hero_image {
            url_1200_630
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

gatsby-config.js:

```
plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-graphql`,
      options: {
        typeName: `HUBAPI`,
        fieldName: `umdHub`,
        url: `https://umd-hub-middleware.herokuapp.com/graphql`,
      },
    },
...
```

Comment: Hi Brooksrelyt, do you mean to pass the article's id to your template, so you can use it in the graphql query there (in `articles(id: $id)`)? If so, you'd need to pass the id as a context to `createPage`, i.e `context: { id: data.id, slug: ... }`

Comment: Thats the intended result but, I am getting errors. `console.log(data)` is returning undefined and there is a 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'umdHub' of undefined' for `{data.umdHub.articles.data.map((article) => (...`

Comment: do you see any error related to `$id` in the console? otherwise, is the path of `articleTemplate` correct?

Comment: `Errors: Variable "$id" of required type "String!" was not provided.`

Comment: Turns out the id had to be 'id: `${data.id}`,' I didnt include the brackets. Thanks for the help!

Comment: nice, glad you got it!